# jQuery Toggle Behaving Strangely with Bootstrap 4 Flex Layout

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two side-by-side 'widgets' that are comprised of a container, header and body (similar to a panel). I want to be able to roll these up individually and when I was using floats with bootstrap three I was able to, so I know the JS is working with no issues. Now I have to roll up both panels to see the effect of the toggle. I'm pretty sure it's the flex layout that causing the issue, but I'm not sure on the fix.

The HTML is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="widget col">
    <div class="widget-heading">
      Widget Title <span>Subtitle</span>
      <div class="widget-controls">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up collapse-widget"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-cog edit-widget"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-close close-widget"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      Stuff
    </div>
  </div>    
  <div class="widget col">
    <div class="widget-heading">
      Widget Title <span>Subtitle</span>
      <div class="widget-controls">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up collapse-widget"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-cog edit-widget"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-close close-widget"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      Stuff
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS/SASS is:

```
.widget {
    background: #444;
    border-top: 3px solid #FF0000;
    margin: 0 1.5%;
    .widget-heading {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;
        padding: 8px 18px 12px 14px;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        letter-spacing: 0.075em;
        font-weight: bold;
        span {
            color: darken(#333, 15%);
            font-size: 0.7rem;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
        .widget-controls {
            color: #FFF;
            font-weight: 700;
            right: 0;
            width: 30%;
            float: right;
            text-align: right;
            i {
                margin-left: 3px;
                font-size: 0.8rem;
                &:hover {
                    color: darken(#000, 15%);
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .widget-body {
        height: 360px;
    }
}
```

And the JS:

```
$('.collapse-widget').click(function(){
    var link = $(this);
    var widget = link.closest(".widget");
    var body = widget.find(".widget-body");
    body.toggle();
    link.toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down");
});
```

I also have a CodePen of the issue here so you can see exactly what I mean:
https://codepen.io/WebDevelopWolf/pen/eemWjw

Comment: Its working fine in the codepen. You have declared the click function to toggle `.widget-body` and its doing that. Is there something that I missed?

Comment: Both of them need to be toggled for them to roll-up - I want to be able to roll them up individually